# Where can I get Chromium binaries?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, installation, browser, chromium

I want to have Chromium on my Windows machine, but I find only instructions how to make it from sources on official site.

Are there any official pre-built binaries?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Since the link to the snapshots seems to change more often then I can keep track off I recommend using this link [Chromium AppSpot Download](http://download-chromium.appspot.com/) to download the latest binaries for each OS. It detects your OS and then offers the latest build automagically.

You can find snapshots of all the nightly builds of Chromium here:

[Chromium Builds](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html)

Each OS has a folder and the latest version number is available under the Latest folder or just sort by date descending.

Comment: Is there something like latest stable chromium build?

Comment: @Andrew. No, unless you use Chrome. Chromium doesn't have a stable release, as they are continually in development. Basically Chromium has a new version every day, but you can stick with a version for about a month before you need to upgrade. I used both and apart from the icons and the sharing of info with Google, there is no functional difference between the two.

Comment: there are Chromium "source releases". What about those? The revisions are different from the nightlies, but they're just as frequent. Nothing stable about those too?

Comment: @Daniel. My understanding from the Chromium website and blog is there will never be a stable release, and Chrome opted for a stable cycle in development. It is up to each user to decide which version is "stable" to them. I stopped using it solely because of the lack of PDF viewing that Chrome does have.

Comment: OK thanks. I was just wondering what [these "releases"](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/releases/) were for. But they're source anyway, so probably of limited use for regular folk.

Comment: +1 for finding a Chromium binary that's not unbelievably outdated. :D Yay for Linux support, too!

Comment: `Win/` folder shows nothing for me. Looks like this site is kinda broken.

Comment: @Diago Concerning PDF viewing in Chromium, you can simply copy pdf.dll from Chrome installation to Chromium directory, and PDF viewing will be enabled automatically.

Comment: I just downloaded the Android version, but where are the developer tools?

Comment: I want only Binaries for QUIC Protocol both client and sever, can I get it from here ?

Comment: Is it safe? Could be a modified version capturing personal information....

Answer (score 20):

As stated by Diago, you can download binary releases via the [chromium-browser-snapshots](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html) repository. Combine this with a quick check of which `version_number` you need at [omahaproxy](http://omahaproxy.appspot.com/viewer), and you get a nice direct link to your desired "stable release" without accessing the slow snapshot lister website.

[`http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?path=Win/ + version_number + /`](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?path=Win/)

Don't forget the slash at the end. For example, the current "dev release", at the point of this writing is `113143`, and can be found at: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?path=Win/113143/

I guess this was what you were looking for.

Comment: `version_number` doesn't seem to be a column anymore?

Answer (score 17):

If you prefer to use only latest **stable** Chromium release (or latest **good** Chromium build, for Windows users), check this website: http://chromium.woolyss.com/ The site is auto-updated each day.

Comment: If you don't trust woolyss.com, note the stable build number and download it from http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?path=Win/

Comment: @Gnubie: Woolyss uses that source..

Comment: Works ok. Using last 3 years. No ads, trojans, etc (Malwarebytes, AdwCleaner, etc).

Answer (score 4):

You can also find links to most recent builds here: http://getchromium.wasil.org/

This is my site, which I made after facing some frustration while looking for newest builds myself. Just wanted to help people like me :)

It dynamically generates links to newest builds every time you refresh.

BTW: those links go to original build repository mentioned by Diago, so this is merely a wrapper site which does not host any files by itself.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

In the same way, you can use this website to **get the latest stable version of Chromium** for Windows, Android, Mac and Linux, from the **official repository** :

[http://downloadchromium.com](http://downloadchromium.com/)

Simple, fast and efficient.

Comment: Does not seem to be available anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As of December 2013, the best source for Chromium binaries you might actually want to use -- as in, ones that aren't potentially very unstable (trunk) -- is http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel

Answer (score -1):

Here are all the mac/linux/win stable chromium binaries:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bugazelle/chromium-all-old-stable-versions/master/chromium.stable.json

The project crawl the http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html, and get all the stable chromium binaries.

We don't need to find its positions and search the commondatastorage.googleapis.com any more.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Welcome to Super User, but please don't post the same answer to multiple questions. If the answer is the same, the questions are probably duplicates anyhow. Also, it seems https://github.com/Bugazelle/chromium-all-old-stable-versions would be a better link, as it explains what the JSON content is actually about, and how it's to be used.

Comment: @Arjan Apologies for the inconvenient. And I know the rule now. Thank you for your guide.

Comment: The site stopped working at version 91!