# Where can I download Chromium-browser for Windows?

Tags: windows, browser, download, url, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I get chromium binaries?](https://superuser.com/questions/203606/where-can-i-get-chromium-binaries)

Where can I download Chromium-browser for Windows builds? Not on the website. In major Linux distros it's easy, binaries are usually in the repositories. But for Windows it's neatly hidden, because of course Google wants you to download Chrome instead (which IS offered on the [Chromium website](http://www.chromium.org/)).

Used to be [here](http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/snapshots/). But it's empty (or hidden?) now.

I am not looking for softpedia/download/brothersoft etc. links with toolbars and custom installers, just the clean latest builds that are considered somewhat stable.

**--upate--**

All three answers have unique links, so I accepted the best one and upvoted the others.

Seems the autobuilds are now here:
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?path=Win/
(note: slow page)

It's a shame Windows binaries aren't offered here:
http://www.getchromium.org/

Still looking for some 'authority' to assign certain builds as 'accepted for mainstream usage' because [as you can see here](http://chromium-build-master.appspot.com/p/chromium/console) (note 1: at least at the moment of writing, chromium-links seem to die fast. note 2: Changes faaast with all the builds) some builds are very good, and others are very buggy until they improve.

I suspect package maintainers for e.g. Ubuntu pick the better ones for repository updates.

**--upate--**

[Here is a nifty tool](http://dirhael.dcmembers.com/cnu/) for automatically downloading the latest version. :)
It's called Chromium Nightly Updater. It takes some time to check for updates, but it finds a later build than the latest build in the snapshot folder.

[image: Chromium Nightly Updater]

Comment: [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows) are the instructions on how to build it out on windows

Comment: Oh, and someone else already asked this question on SU, it links the same place as I do below: http://superuser.com/questions/203606/where-can-i-get-chromium-binaries

Comment: Nice catch. Unfortunately it wasn't offered as **Questions with similar titles** and I found the outdated links using a similar query in google.

Comment: Here is yet another chromium updater: https://github.com/Heather/Cr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html?path=Win/) is the output of the Chromium continuous integration build system for Windows.

The directories are named for the source control revisions. The builds are therefore likely unstable, because no manual testing has been done, and nobody decided to make them into a release. If it compiles, it's there.

Despite the file name, it contains the Chromium browser. I'm on OS X, and the builds look good.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The latest snapshot build (March of 2011) appears to be here: http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/snapshots.old/Win/79315/

Searching through the FTP hierarchy, I could not find any other Windows binary or installer packages.

UPDATE: They moved it to googleapis hosting:

http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?path=Win/124176/

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://codereview.chromium.org/5542002) is a bug report talking about the servers in use. And [here](http://gsdview.appspot.com/chromium-browser-official/) are the pre-builts on one of those servers. [This](http://gsdview.appspot.com/chromium-browser-official/chromium-19.0.1056.0.tar.bz2) is the pre-built from today